# Retrieve Google Maps API Key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Places API requires an API key. I remembered I registered for one and used it successfully, but this was several months ago. Now I can't find this key!! Any clue of where I can look it up again? I tried to look through my Google account but no success!

Thanks,

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to use the Places API you do need a developer key, at least if you want to go over 1000 queries a day. You registered for it in the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), and you can find it again there.

Comment: can you describe where in the console this is?  I've looked everywhere.

Comment: Follow the **Google API Console link** from answer, **Select your Project**, Click on the top left logo (**Google APIs**), this will randomly move you to a different page where you can click on **Credentials**

Comment: I literally come to this page every time now.  So much quicker than trying to Google it.

Comment: Thank you for this!... such a terrible unintuitive way to access the api keys

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work for me - I 'lost' my API Key ages ago

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key